# Почему останавливается именно на этом - sda.Fill(dt)?

Tags: c#, c, .net, mysql, sql

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        SqlCommandBuilder scb;
        DataTable dt;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition/v3.5/Samples/Northwind.sdf;");
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT [Order ID], [Customer ID], [Employee ID], [Ship City], [Ship Region], [Ship Postal Code], [Ship Country], [Ship Via], [Order Date], [Required Date], [Shipped Date], 
                         Freight, [Ship Name], [Ship Address] FROM Orders", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            sda.Update(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки программа зависает и спустя некоторое время появляется ошибка вот эта:

> При установлении соединения с SQL
> Server произошла ошибка, связанная с
> сетью или с определенным экземпляром.
> Сервер не найден или недоступен.
> Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано
> правильно и что на SQL Server
> разрешены удаленные соединения.
> (provider: Поставщик именованных
> каналов, error: 40 - Не удалось
> открыть подключение к SQL Server)

И показано, что программа останавливается на этом этапе - `sda.Fill(dt);`. Что делать, подскажите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы используете класс `SqlConnection` для подключения к Sql Server Compact Edition. Нужно использовать `SqlCeConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Строку соединения с БД проверьте вашу, плюс посмотрите, разрешены ли удаленные подключения к SQL Server.